# RecyclerView has no layout manager

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've seen lots of these questions, but I don't have any child elements so I don't know why this isn't working properly. I moved this to a fragment from an activity and it's no longer working. I saw previous questions have issues with having child elements from the recyclerview but that's not the case here. Here's my code:

```
public class TodoListFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.todo_recycler_view)
    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @BindView(R.id.fab)
    protected FloatingActionButton mFab;

    private TodoListAdapter mTodoListAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public static TodoListFragment newInstance() {
        return new TodoListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_list_recycler_view, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mTodoListAdapter = new TodoListAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mTodoListAdapter);


        return view;
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.fab)
    public void onAdd() {
        TodoItemView todoItemView = new TodoItemView(getContext());
        todoItemView.setText("Schedule a dentist's appointment");
        todoItemView.setTime(new Date());
        mTodoListAdapter.addItem(todoItemView);
    }
}
```

And here's the todo_list_recycler_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                        android:id="@+id/todo_recycler_view"
                                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                                        tools:context=".presentation.TodoActivity"
                                        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_todo_list" />
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.generateLayoutParams(RecyclerView.java:3393)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:502)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                    at com.vorple.shortlist.shortlist.presentation.TodoListFragment.onCreateView(TodoListFragment.java:44)
```

Comment: Can you include your adapter if possible? I need to run in my pc.

Comment: Sure thing, here here it is: http://pastebin.com/qC40tieM

Comment: And in case you need the model object: http://pastebin.com/5GQiwuqf

Comment: Wow, your view is so complex. I think you should simplify the view. Right now, you are having view in a list, and inside every view got another view. And every time when you add your model in adapter, you re-inflate again the view. View suppose to be used once and recycled.

Comment: Perhaps it is overly complex, but isn't the custom view being recycled properly? In bindViewHolder I only change the text and time text view instead of creating a new object. In the future I plan to add more data to each row, that's why I went with creating a custom view. NOTE: This was all working fine in an Activity, so even if it is overly complex it doesn't explain the exception IMO (correct me if I'm misunderstanding)

Comment: The custom view is not a big problem. But how you inflate the view is very complex. Btw, I am rebuilding your layout right now, can you attached a screenshot how is your view look like?

Comment: Sure, here it is http://i.imgur.com/uO1LWlE.png

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving this line

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

after the line where you assign the layout manager to the recycler view. You may need the layout manager declared before you can call setHasFixedSize

Comment: Tried it, didn't seem to work. I don't think it matters anyways though since the exception is occurring on the inflater.inflate method call.

Answer (score 0):

try adding your recyclerview manager in another method override, there may be work going on with Butterknife and the object, what happens when you add the layout manager in, say onResume , or when the data needs to load.

Comment: Doesn't help, the exception is occurring on the inflater.inflate method call; the exception is hit before I call any of the recyclerview/layoutmanager objects.

Answer (score 0):

I am very confuse with what you want to achieve with `TodoItemView` ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lijFd.png)) class. Inside `init()` method, you are inflating another view which I assumed you want to use this class to display the item in list. The problem arise inside this class which, based on your logic, every time you add a model, you will re-inflate the view. It supposed to be inflated once, then store the reference and simply grab back the view when you add another item. In this case, I don't think recyclerView capable to recycle your view.

So, I have recreated a scenario and simplified your code. But I am not sure if this is the exact solution of your problem. But, maybe you can find something useful here.

1) Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private Button playBtn, startActivityBtn;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.mainContent, new TododFragment())
            .commit();

}
}
```

2) Fragment

```
public class TododFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private TodoListAdapter mTodoListAdapter;

public TododFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todod, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.todo_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mTodoListAdapter = new TodoListAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mTodoListAdapter);

    //Create 10 dummies data
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            mTodoListAdapter.addItem(new TodoItem("Schedule a dentist's appointment", dt.format(new Date()), 0));
        else
            mTodoListAdapter.addItem(new TodoItem("Schedule a dentist's appointment", dt.format(new Date()), 1));
    }
}
}
```

3) Model

```
public class TodoItem {
private String text;
private String time;
//LayoutType is used to display different layout.
private int layoutType;

public TodoItem(String text, String time, int layoutType) {
    this.text = text;
    this.time = time;
    this.layoutType = layoutType;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public int getLayoutType() {
    return layoutType;
}

public void setLayoutType(int layoutType) {
    this.layoutType = layoutType;
}
}
```

4) Adapter (In this case, I have two layout. If you want to use one layout, remove `getItemViewType`)

```
public class TodoListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoListAdapter.TodoItemViewHolder> {
private List<TodoItem> mItems;


public static class TodoItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView mTextViewText;
    public TextView mTextViewTime;

    public TodoItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mTextViewText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mTextViewText);
        mTextViewTime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mTextViewTime);
    }
}

public TodoListAdapter() {
    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //ItemViewType will return an int for every row. You can use this to control with layout you want to display
    return mItems.get(position).getLayoutType();
}

@Override
public TodoItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    //get the viewType and display the layout accordingly
    View view = null;
    if(viewType == 0){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.todo_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    else{
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.todo_list_item2, parent, false);
    }

    TodoItemViewHolder rcv = new TodoItemViewHolder(view);
    return rcv;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TodoItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextViewText.setText(mItems.get(position).getText());
    holder.mTextViewTime.setText(mItems.get(position).getTime());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

public void addItem(TodoItem item) {
    mItems.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(mItems.size() - 1);
}
}
```

6) Result
[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for writing up this working example. The whole idea of TodoItemView though is to provide a custom view that I can include in other fragments/layouts throughout my app. Is there no way to include that within a recyclerview within a fragment (keep in mind this was all working with TodoItemView when I only had an activity)?

Comment: If that is the case, you also can create a constructor TodoListAdapter(int layoutResource) and pass the reference of the layout like this mTodoListAdapter = new TodoListAdapter(R.layout.yourlayout). If you are using the same adapter throughout your app.

Comment: Figured out the root cause of the issue, I was including the todo_recycler_view layout within my activity's XML file. I changed that to just be an empty FrameLayout and replaced that FrameLayout with todo_recycler_view in my fragment. Using TodoItemView still works fine in the adapter

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause of the exception.

Here is what I changed within my activity's XML file:

```
<!-- <include layout="@layout/todo_list_recycler_view" /> -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/todo_list_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Instead of including @layout/todo_list_recycler_view in the activity's layout file, I just replaced the empty FrameLayout with todo_list_recycler_view when instantiating my fragment and that gets rid of the exception. I'm not sure why this is the case but it solves the issue for me.